# Memory mapped registers in Python

Tags: python, device-driver

Has anyone come up with a good solution for working with memory-mapped device registers under Python?  Ideally, something that would allow me to work with named registers, and even named bitfields in those registers, in a way that's not entirely ad hoc?  Ideally cross-platform, but I can live with Linux only.

It seems like some combination of mmap and ctypes Structs might be able to handle it, but a) Structs don't seem to allow you to specify bitfield locations (nor do they in C, so...), and b) I can't figure out how I would drop a Struct mapping on top of an mmap.

Or am I fundamentally asking how I can use a circ saw as a screwdriver?  (i.e. It doesn't do that and why on earth would you want to?)

An example in C (untested, NOT for use) would be something like:

```
volatile struct {
    uint32_t mfr_id;
    uint32_t prod_id;
    uint32_t ctl;
    uint32_t dummy[5];
    ...
} * pDev;
hFile = open('/dev/bridge', O_RDWR)
pDev = mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, hFile, 0);
assert(pDev->mfr_id == 0x12345678);
assert(pDev->prod_id == 0xDEADBEEF);

uint32_t temp = pDev->ctl;
temp &= CTL_ACCESS_MASK | CTL_SHIFT_MASK;
temp |= CTL_ACCESS_RO | CTL_SHIFT_5;
pDev->ctl = temp;
```

Comment: I don't know the answer, but if there isn't a library for it already, creating one would be a good project!

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Please provide details of the actual problem you are trying to solve. (I get the feeling you may be trying to talk to a serial or parallel port; there are libraries for that.)

Comment: The [bitstring](http://code.google.com/p/python-bitstring/) module is good at bitfield manipulation....but doesn't help you with getting at the data in the first place.

Comment: @Li-aungYip, I wish.  No, the ultimate goal is to be talking to VME cards over a PCIe-VME bridge.  The bridge will have a real kernel space driver, allowing ranges of the VME address space to be mapped as PCI memory space, but doing kernel space drivers for each VME card is unfeasible and should really be unnecessary.

Comment: Most likley this can be done with ctypes,a s you said - but we'd need more information on how to do that to start with.  Can you link to an example in C for comunicating with memory mapped device registers?

Comment: @jsbueno, example added.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to go is to write accessor functions in C and invoke them from Python (between ctypes and Cython, calling C code from Python isn't that hard).